# Are there any symbols left?

Tags: terminology, notation

I have looked through most of the symbols used in physics and math. It seems like there are none left in the alphabet and the greek alphabet. Are we screwed if we find a new constant?

**Edit:** How do scientist choose symbols for new constants or other things?

Comment: No, we reuse them all the time, or we put on subscripts. For example, $m_t$ is the mass of the top quark.

Comment: You can start using Hebrew alphabet. Which is already being used in mathematics (Aleph, Gimel, etc.)

Comment: See [Physics alphabet](http://www.cyberphysics.co.uk/general_pages/alphabet.html)

Comment: There's still [Tengwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengwar) to use.

Comment: This reads like a bad joke.

Comment: Sorry for the terrible wording.